# Plotting ROC curve in R

Tags: r, roc

This may be a trivial question but I cant answer it myself.

Suppose we have clinical data for patients and healthy controls. how can we draw an ROC curve in R?

```
set.seed(1)
patients=rnorm (20)
control= 1+ rnorm (30)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pROC library for that:

```
library("pROC")
my_roc <- roc(controls = control, cases = patients)
plot(my_roc)
```

[image]